# Product image display in product list and featured product page, but not display in detail page of magento

Tags: php, magento

This is the part of code that calls the media.phtml

```
    <div class="product-img-box">

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>

    </div>
```

I have checked this on frontend and found that nothing come between these div, that`s
 why the images are not displayed in detail page. I have checked and run same code on localhost it`s working.
But not working on live site.
Can any one tell are fix my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you marked **Radio button** for product image as **Base Image** in Administration area on live site? This radio button causes to display the product image on Product detail Page. please check.

[image]

Comment: I have already marked all radio. My problem is, images are not displaying when we click on a product and go to product detail page. On rest pages eg. featured product, category product images are working but when we click for product detail page there is no image. Hope you understand my query.

Comment: Check if media folder has proper permissions set.

Comment: Folder permission and memory limit is OK. While playing around with code i got some idea. that <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?> this code not proper calling my media.phtml file.  So i have copy media.phtml file code and replace with above line. Now, images are displayed. I don`t know it`s right way are not. But i am about to reach with my SOLUTION> If any body can provide another best way, please share, because i know my solution is not a right way. Hope someone comes with a right answer.

Comment: It seems your media.phtml is overridding by another module. Have you installed any module regarding product detail page. If yes, then please try to disable them and check again. If not, then please check catalog.xml and find the tag <catalog_product_view>, you'll find here media.phtml as template name. If it is not available then it is a problem of xml file.

Comment: I have search for <catalog_product_view> tag, in catalog.xml, but its no longer exists there. Can you please share code for that. Also image zooming and more views are not displayed.

Comment: You can copy the code from Base files to your custom theme file. Goto app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml then copy the code for <catalog_product_view> and paste it to app/design/frontend/[Your_theme]/layout/catalog.xml. Hope it will work.

Comment: I have added additional div <div class="product_images_exhibit"></> with same some code, Then images are displayed twice, after that commenting the code inside the div. And it works.  I got back my old setting with image, zooming effect and more views. But still i am unable to know what is  exactly wrong here. As its my first magento project which have done,  but this issue still in my mind. Whats wrong, if code is OK.  By the way thanks "Anx" for your helping nature.